# Eclipse doesn't open JavaDoc in the browser

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

In Eclipse 2021-12 (4.22.0), I have a maven project that uses `assertJ`, among others. When the mouse hovers over a method or a class from this library, Eclipse shows the appropriate Javadoc in the Javadoc pop-up and in the Javadoc view, as it should. But when I attempt to open the Javadoc in the browser, the browser shows an empty page, without any content. The `url` passed to the browser reads

> http://127.0.0.1:12861/help/nftopic/jar:file:/C:/Users/misa/.m2/repository/org/assertj/assertj-core/3.22.0/assertj-core-3.22.0-javadoc.jar!/org.assertj.core/org/assertj/core/api/Assertions.html#assertThat(double)

The Javadoc jar-file presents at the above-mentioned location, and the `Javadoc location` for the library in the build path is correct:

[image]

(otherwise Eclipse could not show the pop-up Javadoc window), but the address passed to the browser is wrong, it includes the package name, **org.assertj.core/**, that seems to be redundant, it shouldn't be there. The url

> http://127.0.0.1:12861/help/nftopic/jar:file:/C:/Users/misa/.m2/repository/org/assertj/assertj-core/3.22.0/assertj-core-3.22.0-javadoc.jar!/org/assertj/core/api/Assertions.html#assertThat(double)

opens the right Javadoc page. Regarding other libraries whose Javadoc jars are located in the local maven repository, the behavior is the same -- their javadoc don't open in the browser, but if I manually remove the package name from the the browser's address string, the required pages open.

What may be the reason? Who is responsible for building the wrong address string that's passed to the browser, and how can I fix it or what workaround can be used?

Comment: Sounds similar to https://bugs.eclipse.org/574788, but that's supposed to be fixed. Maybe because it's a different part of the UI?

Comment: @nitind In my case, the Javadoc view displays the content correctly, just like the popup Javahelp window in the editor. The issue seems to relate only to the url being passed to the browser.